# Given a line, find a point on the line which is equidistant from two points A and B

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I seem to be missing something obvious here.

I am given a line r: $x + y -2 = 0$
and two points $A = (1,2)$ and $B = (3,4)$

So I decided that I needed to find a point P in which d(AP) = d(BP)

I thus equaled the equations of $d(AP)$ and $d(BP)$, eventually reaching that 
$2y + 6x - 20 = 0$

Taking $y = -3x + 10$, I equaled this equation to the equation of my line, which I took to be 
$y = -x + 2$

This yielded the point $P = (6,-4)$ as a result, which is a point on r. However, when I proceed to calculate d(AP) and d(BP), they are not equal. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What were your “equations of $d(AP)$ and $d(BP)$?”

Comment: This is an exercise in a linear geometry class, can you think of any way to resolve this problem that makes use of techniques involving dot product, vectors, etc?

Comment: Sorry, I meant linear algebra

Comment: Your equation of the bisector is incorrect.

Comment: $ d(AP)= d(BP)$ gives you the radical axis or straight line when $x^2,y^2 $ terms cancel out. I got  $x+y=5, $ please check. Find where this line cuts $ x+y=2 $. They are parallel !

Answer (score 1):

By eyeballing, the bisector (=locus of equal distances) of $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$ should be
$$ x-y+1=0.$$
Check again how you arrived at $2y+6x-20=0$ instead.

Comment: This is an exercise in a linear geometry class, can you think of any way to resolve this problem that makes use of techniques involving dot product, vectors, etc?

Comment: Apologies, I meant a linear algebra class

Answer (score 1):

Bisector should be $$x+y=5$$ and not $2y+6x-20=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The parametric equations of the line r are

$$x=t $$
$$y=2-t $$

$$d ^2(AP)=(1-t)^2+(2-2+t)^2$$
$$d^2 (BP)=(3-t)^2+(4-2+t)^2$$

thus
$$d^2 (AP)=2t^2-2t+1$$
$$=d^2 (BP)=2t^2-2t+13$$

The point P does not exist.

Comment: Does that means that the line in between the two points and the given line are parallels?

Comment: @MaxFt yes {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{} $r:y=2-x$ and $y=5-x $ are parallel.

Comment: This is an exercise in a linear geometry class, can you think of any way to resolve this problem that makes use of techniques involving dot product, vectors, etc?

Comment: Apologies, I meant linear algebra

Answer (score 1):

The line containing $A$ and $B$ is $x - y +1=0$

This line is perpendicular to $x+y+2 = 0.$  Which means that the only way that a point on the line $x+y+2=0$ is the same distance to $A$ as to $B$ is if the line perpendicularly bisects $AB.$ (which it doesn't)  And if it did, then every point on the line would be equal distance from $A$ as it is to $B.$